# why have error install pulseaudio with libtool?

Tags: centos7, libtool, pulseaudio

I am trying to install pulse audio but get the following error:

```
# ./configure
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes

checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... yes

checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes

checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes

checking whether to build shared libraries... yes

checking whether to build static libraries... no

checking ltdl.h usability... no

checking ltdl.h presence... no

checking for ltdl.h... no

configure: error: Unable to find libltdl version 2. Makes sure you have libtool 2.2 or later installed.

# yum install libtool
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Package libtool-2.2.6-11.fc11.1.i586 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Why is it not found if installed?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Do you have that lib installed at your system?

Comment: yes, i was installed, remove and install again but failf

Comment: yum install libtool /
Package libtool-2.4.2-22.el7_3.x86_64 already installed and latest

Comment: You installed as root and also installed all the dependencies? When you uninstalled, did you uninstall the things that depend on it? You may need other updates.

Comment: yes, i install as root. when i install have error but ==> "ps aux | grep pulseaudio                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                            hungtv    12592  0.0  0.1 553848  6904 ?        S<l  20:45   0:01 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
hungtv    13920  0.0  0.0 112644   972 pts/2    S+   22:27   0:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio"

Comment: pulseaudio --start
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {f310404109614ac8a899ad1e05b75ced}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native, which appears to be local. Probing deeper.
[hungtv@localhost bin]$

Answer (score 3):

`./configure` is looking for the header `ltdl.h` so you need to
install the `libtdl` development package:

```
yum install libtool-ltdl-devel
```

Comment: Note that yum must be run with root :). Ex: "sudo yum install libtool-ltdl-devel"